# Why doesn't my jQuery ready function call work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to call the `jQuery(document).ready`from jQuery in my main.js file. But I get the following error in the Chrome console:
`main.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Dropdown Test</h1>

    <div class="menu-bar">

    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-box">
        <div class="dropdown-label" onmouseover="
        (function(){main.onLabelHover();})()
        ">
            Erbjudanden
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown-option">
                Option 1
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-option">
                Option 2
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-option">
                Option 3
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-option">
                Option 4
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-option">
                Option 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

main.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("jQuery is working!");
});​

// var main = {

//     run() {
//         document.body.addEventListener('click', this.onAnyClick, true);
//     },

//     onAnyClick() {
//         alert("click");
//     },

//     onLabelHover: function() {
//         this.openDropdown();
//     },

//     openDropdown() {
//         var options = this.getDropdownOptions();
//         console.log(options);
//         for (let option of options) {
//             option.classList.add("dropdown-option-opened")
//         }
//     },

//     getDropdownOptions() {
//         var options = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-option");
//         return options;
//     }

// };
```

The import from node_modules works because I get no complaint in the console regarding finding jQuery in the file system. I even tried getting jQuery from a Google api url, but still the same error when calling the `jQuery(document).ready` function.

I also tried the `$` syntax instead of typing `jQuery`, but the same error persists.

Thanks!

Comment: This code seems way too elaborate. Why are all your functions in a variable? And you are using jQuery so don't need to use vanilla js you can use jQuery selectors and events.

Comment: `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`  could you change this part with ` https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js ' and try again, please?

Comment: @NathanielFlick it's a way to create a "class" or "namespace" in javascript. I have done this in many projects before so it should work.

Comment: @EggBender it seems odd to do it this way and you're not taking advantage of jQuery. But I know this comment is not a solution to your problem.

Comment: @MahirÖzdin tried it but still doesn't work. Doesn't seem to be any problems with the import itself. This is running in Chrome on a Mac, guess it shouldn't matter but in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it and it works fine, but for some reason, you have a hidden character right by your comma.

you have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("jQuery is working!");
});​ // here delete this command and add it again and save it
```

Deleting the comma and adding it again will fix it. Don't forget to save it.

Comment: Wow, can't believe it. Thank you so much for the help. Guess I need to be more aware of annoying hidden characters in the future. It works now.

Comment: @EggBender You're welcome :). It happens sometimes. Usually, those types of scenarios could be capture by using JSLint. Happy coding.